# How do/Should I persist a ClaimsPrincipal?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, wif, claims-based-identity

I've just watched the [Introduction to Identity and Access Control in .NET 4.5 video on Pluralsight](http://beta.pluralsight.com/courses/iac-intro).  I am trying to convert an old webforms app (not MVC and not OWIN) from this...

```
Dim authTicket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "Bob", DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime(), DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime.AddMinutes(60), False, "Master")
Dim authCookie As New HttpCookie("MyApp", FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket))
```

...to a `ClaimsIdentity` and claims-based approach.  Although `ClaimsIdentity` and its Claims are covered in the video, there is little mention of how to plug it all together and persist a user across pages (the stuff that's been done automatically before now).

For example, is this a valid alternative to the above for setting up the user's claims?

```
Dim fd As New FormsIdentity(New FormsAuthenticationTicket("MyApp", True, 60))
fd.AddClaims(New List(Of Claim) From {
 New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob"),
    New Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Master")
})
Dim p As New ClaimsPrincipal(fd)
```

If so, how is `ClaimsPrincipal` then stored/persisted/retrieved on subsequent pages?
Currently I'm not using OWIN, but can introduce it if it will benefit this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK A `ClaimsPrincipal` is always converted to some kind of SecurityToken when "serialized".  If it is sent by an STS this is a SAML or JWT security token.  If is is remembered during a session then it is a `SessionSecurityToken`.  Each of these tokens has a corresponding `SecurityTokenHandler` class.

In classical ASP.NET/MVC, You have two http modules : `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` and `SessionAuthenticationModule`. The latter makes sure the `ClaimsPrincipal` is stored across a session.  By default, WIF uses a `SessionSecurityTokenHandler` and stores the `ClaimsPrincipal` in a bunch of cookies.

So your question becomes easier once you know that the road to serializaing a `ClaimsPrincipal` goes over a `SecurityToken`. You first convert it to a `SecurityToken` and then use a handler to "convert it to a string".

For you it boils down to instantiating the correct `SecurityTokenHandler` derivate. To deserialize it, you just call `ValidateToken` (which is a great method name to deserialize a token).  This gives you a list of claims, which can easily be converted in a `ClaimsIdentity` and a `ClaimsPrincipal`.

To serialize it, you might have to pass over a `SecurityTokenDescriptor` (where you put your claims in) to convert your `ClaimsPrincipal` into a `SecurityToken`, then the `SecurityTokenHandler` can convert this into a "string".

Comment: Thanks Willy.  I will read up on these subjects today.  It seems strange having to do all this manually, when it was all hard-baked into ASP.NET 2.0+ and happened automagically...

Comment: I found the answer with `SessionSecurityToken` and `SessionAuthenticationModule`, the latter of which requires some hefty additions to web.config